# Prove that if $a$ and $a-1$ are relatively prime to $n$ then $1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{\varphi(n)-1}\equiv 0 \pmod n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I think I'm off to the right start where I applied Euler's Theorem and got:
$$a^{\varphi(n)}-(a-1)^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 0 \pmod n. $$

But I'm not sure how to proceed or if I have the right idea.

Comment: are you sure the sum is up to $a^{\varphi(n)}$ and not $a^{\varphi(n)-1}$?

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed it. I meant the sum to go up to a^φ(n)−1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** What is 
$$(1-a)(1+a+a^2+....+a^{\phi(n)-1})=?$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I figured it out

Answer (score 2):

$1+a+a^2+\dots a^m$ is in general $\frac{a^m-1}{a-1}$

So in this case $1+a+a^2+\dots a^{\varphi(n)-1}$ is equal to:

$\frac{a^{\varphi(n)}-1}{a-1}$. By euler's theorem $a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1 \bmod 0$, so the denominator is a multiple of $n$.

Since $a-1$ is relatively prime to $n$ we have that $\frac{a^{\varphi(n)}-1}{a-1}$ is a multiple of $n$. (Because a multiple of $n$ is still a multiple of $n$ after dividing by a number that is relatively prime to $n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ (a,n)=1\,\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv a^\phi-1 \equiv (a\!-\!1) f(a),\,\,$ and  $\,a\!-\!1\,$ is cancellable by $\,(a\!-\!1,n)=1$